# change interface from IUnknown to IDispatch

Tags: com, vtable, idispatch, iunknown

I have a COM class which is accessible only via vtable. It is already distributed to clients. I am planning to allow script access as well, by introducing IDispatch.

In my local tests, it shows client code will not change, but they will require code rebuild, why so?

Comment: It is not a breaking change.  Hard to guess, maybe the client-side tooling thinks it is necessary because the type library changed.

Comment: Did you change your main interface to now inherit from IDispatch instead of inheriting from IUnknown? You can't change the inheritance list on a published interface anymore that you can change the list of methods or their arguments. Doing so would cause the vtable slots to shift down to make space for the IDispatch methods.

Comment: yes, exactly. I changed the inheritance to IDispatch from IUnknown. I guess you are right.

Comment: You don't have to make the vtable , `IUnknown` interface inherit from `IDispatch`, only the object itself must implement `IDispatch`, which is not a breaking change.

Comment: @PauloMadeira yes it is not a breaking change **code wise**, but binary compatibility is broken. As EuroMicelli explains, since older client binaries are not prepared to accept additional `IDispatch` methods' entries in vtable after `IUnknown` and before methods of interest.

Comment: @Logan, I'm sorry, I didn't make myself clear.  An object may implement many interfaces, and you don't even have to declare them all in a type library's coclass (heck, you may have an object in hands that didn't come from a class factory).  You can keep the vtable interface and just add `IDispatch` to the **class** bases.  You never touch the vtable interface's definition at all in the process.

Comment: @acelent What do you mean  "IUnknown interface inherit from IDispatch"? That's absolutely NOT true, they are two distinct interfaces and neither inherits from the other.

Comment: @amn, it seems I mis-edited the comment before I posted it. What I meant was "you don't have to make the vtable of the already published interfaces and classes inherit from `IDispatch`, leave them as inheriting from `IUnknown` to make sure you don't break anything; to add scripting support, you only need to make the actual object implement `IDispatch` somehow in `QueryInterface`." However, `IDispatch` inherits from `IUnknown`; in fact, all COM interfaces do.

Comment: Yes, you are right about IDispatch inheriting from IUknown -- I made a mistake there.